# RedHat 7 Dual Screen xrdp

Tags: rhel7, xrdp

I am running a RHEL 7.2 server and connecting to it by xrdp (using windows remote desktop). Is there a way to connect to the server and view it using both of my monitors? I've tried selecting the "use all my monitors for the remote session" box in Windows Remote Desktop Connection but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have (sort of) done this on Ubuntu. I don't know if it works for RHEL 7.2. I mostly got my info from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133343/how-do-i-set-up-xrdp-session-that-reuses-an-existing-session) if you want more detail.

Edit the file here:

```
/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

Make an entry at the end of the file that looks like this:

```
[xrdp8]
name=Share-Screens
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=ask
```

When the person you want to share screens with logs in, make note of the port shown in the connection log when they first log in. There will be two ports, make sure it is the second one. When you log in, change the module to "Share-Screens" and enter in the username and password to what the other person used and enter in that port that you took note of.

This works for me, but unfortunately I cannot share screens with a person remotely logged in and with me locally logged in. I hope this might help you, but this post is getting pretty old!